How EstimatedDistribution handles right censored data?
data = Range[10];
c = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
a = EventData[data, c];
EstimatedDistribution[a, WeibullDistribution[x, y]]


WeibullDistribution[1.50867, 7.45903]

Minitab and JMP both give values different from MMA.


The 3 softwares all use MLE for parameter estimation by default. But MMA's results differ a lot.
How should I modify the code so as to obtain the same results as in the other tools?
I did some manual check to verify the estimation.
tValues = Range[1, 7];
cValues = {8, 9, 10};
llle[eta_, beta_] := beta/eta (Sum[(t/eta)^beta, {t, tValues}] - Length[tValues] + Sum[(c/eta)^beta , {c, cValues}])
lllb[eta_, beta_] := Length[tValues]/beta + Sum[Log[t/eta] (1 - (t/eta)^beta), {t, tValues}] - Sum[(c/eta)^beta Log[c/eta], {c, cValues}]
FindRoot[{llle[eta, beta] == 0, lllb[eta, beta] == 0}, {eta, 1}, {beta, 1}]


{eta -> 7.49886, beta -> 1.39643}

From one of the EventData examples in the MMA document, I do see EstimatedDistribution can handle the censored data. Given a data set wi/wo censor labling, we will have different results. And by default MLE is used. But neither EstimatedDistribution nor FindDistributionParameters handles the the censored data in the expected way although both give the same values.

Hmmm.  Using larger numbers gives the expected results:  data = 7 + Range[10];

This is just an extended comment to supplement what you found:  EstimatedDistribution does not produce the correct maximum likelihood estimates for censored data.
Here is an alternative set of code to get the appropriate maximum likelihood estimates.  The log of the likelihood is found and is then maximized:
logL = Sum[Log[PDF[WeibullDistribution[x, y], i]], {i, 1, 7}] +
       Sum[Log[1 - CDF[WeibullDistribution[x, y], i]], {i, 8, 10}] 
mle = FindMaximum[{logL, x > 0 && y > 0}, {{x, 1.50867}, {y, 7.45903}}]
(*  {-20.9771, {x -> 1.39643, y -> 7.49886}} *)

This matches what you found with Minitab (assuming Minitab produced the first table).
A more straightforward approach that uses EventData (and gets the correct answer) is the following:
logL = LogLikelihood[WeibullDistribution[x, y], a]
FindMaximum[{logL, x > 0 && y > 0}, {{x, 1.5}, {y, 7.5}}]
(* {-20.9771, {x -> 1.39643, y -> 7.49886}} *)

The log likelihood surface is nice and smooth so EstimatedDistribution must be doing something else than maximizing the log of the likelihood or doesn't construct the log of the likelihood properly.
Show[ContourPlot[logL, {x, 1.35, 1.55}, {y, 7.4, 7.6}, Contours -> 100],
  ListPlot[{{{1.5086714685589053`, 7.459026235279845`}}, {{1.3964340926915468`, 7.498855434040262`}}},
  PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[0.02], Red}, {PointSize[0.02], Green}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"What EstimatedDistribution produces", "Maximum likelihood estimates"}]]



reassuring that LogLikelihood worked with censored data.

An interesting point is if one sets the method to any documented ones {"NMaximize", "FindRoot", "FindMaximum"} it produces the expected result. Only Automatic will deviate. There is also EvaluatorMonitor to go deeper for curious minds.

@BenIzd That's a much more direct fix than what I wrote.  You should write that as an answer.

Setting the method explicitly can lead to the expected result:
Assuming:
data = Range[10];
c = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
a = EventData[data, c];

Then
EstimatedDistribution[a, WeibullDistribution[x, y], 
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "NMaximize"}]

EstimatedDistribution[a, WeibullDistribution[x, y], 
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "FindMaximum"}]

EstimatedDistribution[a, WeibullDistribution[x, y], 
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "FindRoot"}]

(* Out: WeibullDistribution[1.39643, 7.49886] *)
(* Out: WeibullDistribution[1.39643, 7.49886] *)
(* Out: WeibullDistribution[1.39643, 7.49886] *)

But why? After struggling to read the Trace, I found that setting the following will turn debugging on for optimization:
Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUG = 3
Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`DEBUGMonitor = 1

Now if you execute:
EstimatedDistribution[a, WeibullDistribution[x, y]]

prints:
FindMinimum`InteriorPoint========

before findFixedVars, {lb,ub,vars,prec} {{0.},{\[Infinity]},{x},Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`prec$48543}

{values,unfixed} {{},{1}}

{eqs,ineqs} {{}, {}}

CROPLAMBDA=TrueCROPMATRIX=FalseADAPTIVEPENALTY=FalseCOMPARELASTMERIT=FalseALPHA = 1/100BETA = 99/100THETA = 1AugMERIT= True BarrierFACTOR = 1/10 LineSEARCH = BackTracking BarrierUPDATE = EveryIteration Gradient = {Automatic,DifferenceOrder->2} starting iter = 1 eveluation monitor = {StepMonitor->None,EvaluationMonitor->None} prec = MachinePrecision tol = {1.*10^-6,1.*10^-6,\[Infinity],1.*10^-6} atol = \[Infinity] rtol = 1.*10^-6min constraint improvement factor0.9

point lists {{1.8716},{1.8716}}

InteriorPoint ready to start, {func,vars,lowerb,upperb,eqns,ineqs} {Experimental`NumericalFunction[{Hold[-Statistics`ExtremeValueDistributionsDump`ll[x]], Block}, {0, {{{}, 1, 0, Hold[x], 0, 0}}}, {{{1, 1, 817}, {{Automatic, Automatic, {Hold[Automatic], Block}, 2, Automatic, Automatic}, {}}}}, {8, 3, {}, 0}, {904, MachinePrecision, {Automatic, {Hold[-Statistics`ExtremeValueDistributionsDump`ll[x]], Block}}, True, {{Automatic, "ExpressionOptimization" -> None}, {Automatic, "CleanUpRegisters" -> False, "WarningMessages" -> False, "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False, "RuntimeErrorHandler" -> ($Failed & )}, {}, Automatic, "WVM"}, FindArgMax, Automatic, None}, {None, None, None}], {x}, {0.}, {Infinity}, {}, {}}

IPSolveMessage========

Number of equalities = 0

Number of inequalities = 0

Number of variables = 1

Number vars with lower and upper bounds = 0

Number vars with lower bounds = 1

Number vars with upper bounds = 0

Scaling is used

IPSolveInternal========

SetProblemAndPointsPrecision initial problem {Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`f$48562,1,0,Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`eqs$48562,0,Optimization`NonlinearInteriorPointDump`ineqs$48562,{0.},{\[Infinity]},{1},{1},{},{},{1},{},{},{},None,None,None}

SetProblemAndPointsPrecision parameters {True,False,False,False,0.01,0.99,1.,False,True,7.15307*10^-20,0.5,0.1,BackTracking,500,EveryIteration,{Automatic,DifferenceOrder->2},True,IPOPT,UNUSED,1,True,0.1,1.*10^-11,0.9,{},Automatic,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED,UNUSED}

SetProblemPrecision========

leaving SetProblemPrecision========

getInitialPoint--- {1.,{1.8716}}

SetProblemAndPointsPrecision point start {{1.8716},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}}

IPOPT=============

IPOPTLink`IPOPTMinimize[Experimental`NumericalFunction[{Hold[-Statistics`ExtremeValueDistributionsDump`ll[x]], Block}, {0, {{{}, 1, 0, Hold[x], 0, 0}}}, {{{1, 1, 817}, {{Automatic, Automatic, {Hold[Automatic], Block}, 2, Automatic, Automatic}, {}}}}, {8, 3, {}, 0}, {904, MachinePrecision, {Automatic, {Hold[-Statistics`ExtremeValueDistributionsDump`ll[x]], Block}}, True, {{Automatic, "ExpressionOptimization" -> None}, {Automatic, "CleanUpRegisters" -> False, "WarningMessages" -> False, "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False, "RuntimeErrorHandler" -> ($Failed & )}, {}, Automatic, "WVM"}, FindArgMax, Automatic, None}, {None, None, None}],None,{1.8716},{{0.,1.*10^40}},Experimental`NumericalFunction[{Hold[{x}], Block}, {0, {{{}, 1, 0, Hold[x], 0, 0}}}, {{{1, 1, 817}, {{Automatic, Automatic, {Hold[Automatic], Block}, 2, Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic, None, 1, Automatic, Automatic}}}}, {8, 3, {1}, 0}, {908, MachinePrecision, {Automatic, {Hold[{x}], Block}}, True, {{Automatic, "ExpressionOptimization" -> None}, {Automatic, "CleanUpRegisters" -> False, "WarningMessages" -> False, "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False, "RuntimeErrorHandler" -> ($Failed & )}, {}, Automatic, "WVM"}, Experimental`NumericalFunction, Automatic, Hold[Optimization`InteriorPointExceptionHandler[]]}, {None, None, None}],{{-1.*10^40,1.*10^40}},StepMonitor:>None,IPOPTOptions->{max_iter->500,tol->1.*10^-6},Compiled->Automatic,MessageHead->FindArgMax]

InteriorPoint best pt {1.50867}

InteriorPoint best pt all vars {1.50867}

It appears Mathematica tries to optimize 1 variable, if you check the debug when we set the method explicitly to FindMaximum, you will realize, that the optimizer tries to optimize 2 variables in that case.
The result also confirms the different behaviour of using EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}] with Reap. When no method is specified, the result looks something like this:
{{1.8716, y}, ... }

But if you specify ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "FindMaximum", EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]}, you'll get like the following:
{{0.999994, 1.}, ... }

This means variables x and y are being actively evaluated at each iteration.
In the first case, the y variable is not evaluated, looking a little bit deeper I found, that Mathematica will find a value for variable x, then replace the x in the following to find y for you case:
Block[{x = 1.5086714685589053`}, 
 E^(2.302585092994046` + 
    Log[1/7 (1.` + E^(-2.302585092994046` x) + 
         E^(-1.6094379124341005` x) + E^(-1.2039728043259361` x) + 
         E^(-0.9162907318741553` x) + E^(-0.6931471805599456` x) + 
         E^(-0.5108256237659909` x) + E^(-0.35667494393873267` x) + 
         E^(-0.22314355131421015` x) + E^(-0.10536051565782634` x))]/
     x)]

I am not a Wolfram developer or a statistician or mathematician, how this "InteriorPoint" method works or whether this should be categorized as a bug is something I don't know.
